# Error to load item with RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I know that RecyclerView loads the items again every time to save memory and increase performance. However, I found a problem with the images, that is that when I start to scroll quickly the recyclerView the elements start to recharge in the wrong order. I put the video in description of what happens. How can I resolve this error?

LINK: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwHUYgWIm5g

RecyclerViewAdapter.class

```
    package com.example.mattiaferigutti.chatjava;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerMessegeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerMessegeAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Message> messages;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private StorageReference storageRef;
    private Context mContext;


    public RecyclerMessegeAdapter(List<Message> messages, Context context) {
        this.messages = messages;
        this.mContext = context;
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_single_layout,
                null, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {

        String currentUserId = mAuth.getUid();

        Message currentMessage = messages.get(i);

        String fromUser = currentMessage.getMessageUser();

        if (fromUser.equals(currentUserId) && currentMessage.getMessageType().equals("text")) {
            myViewHolder.textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_text_background);
            myViewHolder.textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            myViewHolder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            myViewHolder.textView.setText(currentMessage.getMessageText());

        } else if (currentMessage.getMessageType().equals("text")) {
            myViewHolder.textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_text_background);
            myViewHolder.textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            myViewHolder.textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            myViewHolder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            myViewHolder.textView.setText(currentMessage.getMessageText());

        } else if (currentMessage.getMessageType().equals("image")) {
            myViewHolder.textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            String url = currentMessage.getMessageText();

            storageRef.child("message_image/" + url + ".jpg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                    Picasso.get()
                            .load(uri)
                            .into(myViewHolder.imageView);
                    myViewHolder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle any errors
                }
            });

        }
    }

    //TODO: mettere il testo a destra o a sinistra

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView textView;
        private ImageView imageView;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.class

```
    package com.example.mattiaferigutti.chatjava;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int GALLERY_PICK = 123;
    //Firebase
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;

    //Storage Firebase
    private StorageReference mImageStorage;

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private String mCurrentUserId;
    private EditText mTextInput;
    private Button mSendBtn;
    private ImageButton mPlusBtn;
    private RecyclerView mMessagesList;
    private final List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerMessegeAdapter mAdapter;

    private String usersDentist = "aaXmkFhvrUWmuzC6GDZAV8a0i0u1";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mImageStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        mSendBtn = findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        mTextInput = findViewById(R.id.textEdit);
        mMessagesList = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mPlusBtn = findViewById(R.id.plusBtn);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Chat");

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null)
        mCurrentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        mAdapter = new RecyclerMessegeAdapter(messages, this);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mMessagesList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mMessagesList.isAttachedToWindow();
        mMessagesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null)
        loadMessages();

        mMessagesList.scrollToPosition(messages.size()-1);

        mSendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String textSend = mTextInput.getText().toString();
                long currentMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

                myRef.child("messages").child(mCurrentUserId).child(usersDentist).push().setValue(new Message(
                        textSend, currentMillis, mCurrentUserId, "text"
                ));


                myRef.child("messages").child(usersDentist).child(mCurrentUserId).push().setValue(new Message(
                        textSend, currentMillis, mCurrentUserId, "text"
                ));


                mTextInput.setText("");
            }
        });


        mPlusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "SELECT IMAGE"),
                        GALLERY_PICK);
            }
        });

    }

    private void loadMessages() {
        myRef.child("messages").child(mCurrentUserId).child(usersDentist).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                //messages.clear();

                Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                messages.add(message);

                /*if (messages.size() > 0) {
                    final LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
                    mMessagesList.setLayoutManager(manager);
                    mAdapter = new RecyclerMessegeAdapter(messages, MainActivity.this);
                    mMessagesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }*/

                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (currentUser == null) {
            sendToStart();
        }
    }

    private void sendToStart() {
        Intent startActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
        startActivity(startActivity);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.account_settings:
                break;

            case R.id.all_users:
                break;

            case R.id.log_out:
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                sendToStart();
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri image = data.getData();

            long currentMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

            final String pushId = String.valueOf(myRef.push());

            myRef.child("messages").child(mCurrentUserId).child(usersDentist).push().setValue(new Message(
                    pushId, currentMillis, mCurrentUserId, "image"
            ));

            myRef.child("messages").child(usersDentist).child(mCurrentUserId).push().setValue(new Message(
                    pushId, currentMillis, mCurrentUserId, "image"
            ));


            StorageReference filePath = mImageStorage.child("message_image").child(pushId + ".jpg");
            filePath.putFile(image).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "succeful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: that happens because some images may be downloaded before each other

Comment: and how I can fix it?

Comment: You can save the index i to your viewholder in onCreateViewHolder and in onBindViewHolder, check if viewholder index is same with i in this and proceed binding your view

Comment: I guess I'll have to do it inside onBindViewHolder () but how do I compare the viewHolder's index to the one that is inflating the view?

Comment: I think I have found a guide that can help me. https://medium.com/@haydar_ai/better-way-to-get-the-item-position-in-androids-recyclerview-820667d435d4

Comment: you have to set place holder for each image ( from its name we can conclude it) it will hold the place of image till its loaded , check out my answer and edit it for ur needs

Comment: can I make sure that the elements are not reloaded after being loaded? ListView Type? I know this would do the opposite of what a RecyclerView needs to do but would fix the bug

Comment: do you mean viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);?

Answer (score 0):

Replace Picasso Part Code with this example:

```
Picasso.get()
.load(url) // url of the image
.placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder) //ur place holder image it could be any image
.error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error) // optional if image is not loaded
.into(imageView); // ur image view
```

For ur case it is like :

```
myViewHolder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Picasso.get()
    .load(uri) // url of the image
    .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) //ur place holder image it could be any image
    .into(myViewHolder.imageView);
```

Comment: I have a solution which is downloading all data before putting them in recycler view , you can use hashMap and the key is item position and then put them according to their key. with pagination ofcourse

Comment: if you need help in implementing it , please let me know so I can do it

Comment: I tried to implement this method but don't work. Probably I've implement it this method in incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your `TextView` visible if message type is `text`.

Add `myViewHolder.textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/QuickBlox/ChatMessagesAdapter-android

ChatMessagesAdapter for Android

QuickBlox simple to use UI library for showing quickblox chat messages inside android application.

## Features

```
Ready-to-go QBChatMessage view adapter with a set of view types.
UI customisation for all message types.
Flexibility in improving and extending functionality.
Easy to connect with Quickblox.
Optimised and performant.
Flexible mechanism for styling layout for chat messages.
Add custom widgets inside predefined layout.
```

this may help